# Why no conductivity with this wire?

Tags: testing, conductivity, continuity

These are two ends of the same cable:

[image]

The cable comes from an old headphone set and I want to re-purpose it.

What are those copper looking wire strands? I could not get connectivity between them and the 3.5mm plug. There is no conductivity even if I place the probes on the same length a short distance apart.

How do I solder the wires to a new connector?

Comment: do you show continuity when you touch the probes together?

Comment: Yes, I did that repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

> There is no conductivity even if I place the probes on the same length a short distance apart.

That is likely because of clear insulating "lacquer" on the copper wire strands, which is difficult to see visually. You need to scrape those wire strands down to the bare wire (e.g. with fine sandpaper or a sharp blade) to make electrical contact.

> How do I solder the wires to a new connector?

Carefully! Some of those insulating "lacquer" coatings will burn off under the heat of a soldering iron, allowing soldering to be successful. However:

- sometimes extra flux is needed;
- sometimes even with extra flux, the lacquer has a high melting point and has to be removed mechanically (e.g. sandpaper) first;
- sometimes the PVC insulation will melt very quickly when trying to solder the wire.